# Is that possible to migrate Titanium app to Android native?

Tags: android, migration, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have project which is build in titanium classic. I need to convert this titanium classic app to Android native app. Is there any tool available for migration?

Comment: I don't think so, only a native Android developer can do it by rebuilding it.

Comment: Second that....